# Passing / altering a jQuery UI drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I'd like users to be able to drag a horizontal menu bar left and right. I realize there are lots of carousel and slider libraries which have this behavior– but none of them fit the situation.

When users drag an `LI`, can it pass the new x-offset information to the **left margin** of the **first** `LI`?

I took a stab at it here: http://jsfiddle.net/n92ng9uz/

The main problem with the above fiddle, is that the offset is still applied to the individual `LI`, and if I prevent the event from bubbling up the dragging is no longer smooth.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What if you just set the draggable on the UL instead of the LI?  $('ul').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    drag: function(e, ui) {
    }
});

Comment: I think it's a common technique in carousels / sliders to use the the `ul` as a container with `white-space:nowrap` applied and apply a negative margin to the first `li` inside. If you were going to integrate jQuery UI with that it would have to follow suit. That's why I can't accept dragging the `ul` as an answer to the question. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specified in the comments that it's a requirement to use `margin-left` on the first `li` element, and not modify the position of the `ul`, I am pretty sure that it can't be easily done using jQuery UI draggable. If we were to make the `li` draggable, we wouldn't catch mouse events on the other `li`s, and if we were to make the `ul` draggable, we couldn't easily make it affect only the `margin-left` of the first `li` and not the position of the `ul`.

Here is a **live demo** of a solution that uses mouse events directly instead of using jQuery UI:

```js
var firstLI = $('li:first-child');

var initx = 0;
var dragstartx = 0;
var dragging = false;

$("ul").mousedown(function(e) {
    dragging = true;
    dragstartx = e.pageX;
    initx = parseInt(firstLI.css("marginLeft"), 10);
});

$("ul").mousemove(function(e) {
    if (dragging) {
        firstLI.css("marginLeft", (initx + e.pageX - dragstartx) + "px");
    }
});

$("ul").mouseleave(function(e) {
    dragging = false;
});

$("ul").mouseup(function(e) {
    dragging = false;
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul > li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: orangered;
}

ul > li:nth-child(even) {
    background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
    <li>Link 5</li>
    <li>Link 6</li>
    <li>Link 7</li>
    <li>Link 8</li>
    <li>Link 9</li>
    <li>Link 10</li>
</ul>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/n92ng9uz/2/

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Nevermind... figured it out... You need to move each item left by the position difference.  I think this is what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/xwesf1Lt/.  Tell me if I'm wrong.  Note that I changed the diff variable to just the left position.

Also, instead of altering the margin, we alter the left attribute.

```
var firstLI = $('ul:first-child')[0];
firstLI.style.marginLeft = 0;

$('li').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    drag: function(e, ui) {
        var diff = ui.position.left;
        console.log(diff);
        var currentLeft = parseInt(firstLI.style.marginLeft, 10);
        var offset = currentLeft + diff + 'px';
        //firstLI.style.marginLeft = diff;
        //  to drag all of them:

        $("li").each(function(index) {
            $(this).css("left", offset);
        });

        // with this enabled, can only be moved 1px at a time..?
        // e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a nice solution IAMZERG. So I'm upvoting because it might be the right solution for someone digging up the problem later. It just doesn't satisfy the the first `li` `margin-left` thing so I can't mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work? Adding the margin to the `ul`? Seems to work in the fiddle!

```
var ul = $('ul');

ul.draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    drag: function(e, ui) {
        ul.css({marginLeft: ui.position - ui.originalPosition});
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the users to be able to **freely drag the navbar** and then it should **drop at the same place** then you can try out the jquery dad plugin. It is by far the best drag and drop plugin I've used do to the simplicity of the code.

[Click here](https://github.com/williammustaffa/jquery.dad.js) to see its demo and documentation if you wish.